# AWS ECS : get public IP of the instance container when start task is called

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I was successful in starting a task using AWS-SDK for node js but this response does not contain the IP address of the instance on which the task was initiated.
Is there any way I can retrieve the IP of the instance in the same reply ?

What are the possible options ? However I do see the containerInstanceArn in the reply.

```
var ecs = new ECS_AWS.ECS({apiVersion: '2014-11-13'});

         var params = {

      family: 'test-code123',
      containerDefinitions: [
          {
              environment: [],
              name: 'simple-app',
              image: 'abc/cbuild:2',
              cpu: 1024,
              memory: 500,
              portMappings: [
                  {
                      containerPort: 8000,
                      hostPort: 8000
                  }
              ],
              command: [
                  'node',
                  '/src1/server.js',
                  '8000'
              ],
              essential: true
          }
      ]

       };

       ecs.registerTaskDefinition(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log("ECS error" + err + err.stack); // an error occurred
          else       console.log(data);
```

Once the task is created I make a runTask API Call

```
var ecs = new ECS_AWS.ECS({apiVersion: '2014-11-13'});
          var params = {
        taskDefinition: 'arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:32:task-definition/test-code123:5', /* required */
        count: 1,

              };
      ecs.runTask(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      });
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the existing ECS apis, there is no direct API to get the IP of the instance where the task started.

You will need to use `describeContainerInstances` API of ecs to get the physical id of the instance and then call ec2 APIs to get the IP of the instance where the task was started.

Comment: yup just went the way. Thanks.

Comment: @Shibashis I have a similar issue, would you mind to give an example?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of how to get the IP for a running task using the AWS SDK:

```js
import { DescribeNetworkInterfacesCommand, EC2Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2"
import { DescribeTasksCommand, ECSClient, ListTasksCommand, Service } from "@aws-sdk/client-ecs"

async function ipForService(service: Service, clusterId: string) {
  const ecs = new ECSClient()
  const ec2 = new EC2Client({})

  if(!service.runningCount) {
    return undefined
  }

  const listTasksCommand = new ListTasksCommand({
    cluster: clusterId,
    serviceName: service.serviceName
  })

  const listTasksResult = await ecs.send(listTasksCommand)
  const taskArns = listTasksResult.taskArns ?? []

  if(!taskArns.length) {
    return undefined
  }

  const describeTasksCommand = new DescribeTasksCommand({
    cluster: clusterId,
    tasks: taskArns,
  })

  const describeTasksResult = await ecs.send(describeTasksCommand)

  // In this example, we assume that there's only one running task
  // Modify this logic if you need the IP for a specific task
  const task = describeTasksResult.tasks![0]
  const taskEni = task.attachments![0].details!.find(detail => detail.name === "networkInterfaceId")!.value!

  const describeNetworkInterfacesCommand = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesCommand({
    NetworkInterfaceIds: [taskEni]
  })

  const describeNetworkInterfacesResult = await ec2.send(describeNetworkInterfacesCommand)

  return describeNetworkInterfacesResult.NetworkInterfaces?.[0].Association?.PublicIp
}
```